# Behavior of C++ templates and operator overloading

Tags: c++

I would like to understand the following code behavior

```
#define USE_FRIEND 

class Foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    Foo& operator<< (T val)
    {
        std::cout << "Inside Foo" << std::endl;

        return *this;
    }
};

class A
{
public:

#ifdef USE_FRIEND
    friend Foo& operator<<(Foo& f, A& a)
    {
        std::cout << "Inside A" << std::endl;

        return f;
    }
#endif
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    Foo f;

#ifdef USE_FRIEND
    std::cout << " using Friend :: ";
#else
    std::cout << " not using Friend :: ";
#endif

    f << a;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the above code for 2 executions, one with Using friend and another without:

**case 1:**

```
using Friend :: Inside A
```

**case 2:**

```
not using Friend :: Inside Foo
```

I can understand case 2, but can anyone explain case 1

Comment: What's to understand? In case 1 you're declaring an additional overload which is a better match...

Comment: Does the compiler always template the functions first and then overloads it?

Comment: The compiler is not relevant.We're talking about C++ in general. First, the overload set is collected, then the best overload is selected. The best overload *may* happen to be a function template, but that's secondary; if it is a template, *then* the template is instantiated.

Comment: It should be noted that template argument deduction is part of the overload resolution process, since template argument deduction determines whether a function template is a viable overload in the first place, and if yes, it determines what sort of conversions are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Overload resolution is complicated business, but here are the two rules that are relevant:

- The overloads that are viable are:

  1. `template <typename T> Foo & Foo::operator<<(T)`
  2. `Foo & operator<<(Foo &, A &)`
- When you call `operator<<(f, a)`, then both overloads match, and they both match on the nose, deducing `T = A` in the template. There is *no difference* in exactness, since a reference counts as a "perfect match".
- Thus the two overloads are tied, and the resolution would appear to be ambiguous. However, there is a tie breaker: No 1 is a template and No 2 is not. In this case, the non-template is  a better match.